# How to count number of running process with given name?

Tags: c++, winapi

How I could check how many instances of an executable is running also checking if each exe has a different PID?

**--Edit--**
What I already got:

The code display the PID correctly but `szProcessName` always return:
[image]

```
void DisplayProcessNameAndID(DWORD processID)
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.  
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
        PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, processID);

    // Get the process name.  
    if (NULL != hProcess)
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        //Given a handle to a process, this returns all the modules running within the process.
        //The first module is the executable running the process,
        //and subsequent handles describe DLLs loaded into the process.
        if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
        {
            //This function returns the short name for a module,
            //typically the file name portion of the EXE or DLL
            GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        }
    }

    // Display the process name and identifier.
    CString str;
    str.Format("Text:%s, PID : %u", szProcessName, processID);
    //AfxMessageBox(str);

    //close the process handle
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

```
void Processes()
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.  
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    //This returns a list of handles to processes running on the system as an array.
    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
        return;

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.  
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Display the name and process identifier for each process.  
    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
        if (aProcesses[i] != 0)
            DisplayProcessNameAndID(aProcesses[i]);
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses

Comment: @paddy thanks i have found some examples using EnumProcesses, I have updated my post

Comment: Store the names in a `std::set`, `std::map` or similar.

Comment: @paddy this example i post is showing PID correctly but the process name don't, any idea why?

Comment: Maybe it's using UTF-16 characters, as is the WIndows default, and you're trying to output with `std::cout`.  I don't know.  Please don't use the comments section for a tutorial on the Win32 API.  If you have a specific question about a specific thing, post a new question, provide sample code, describe the behavior (with example output if possible) and explain why it differs from what you expect.

Comment: *To open a handle to another local process and obtain full access rights, you must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege.* Try to get the return value of `OpenProcess` and call `getlasterror` if it failed, check whether it returns 5(access denied).

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT `hProcess` return 0x00000000000000 and `processID` return the PID correctly

Comment: And then does the following `getlasterror` return 5?

Comment: I dont know how to call getlasterror, I also tried debug with visual studio as admin, and got same value on hProcress 0x000

Comment: Try to use this sample:[Enabling and Disabling Privileges in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) to enable the `"SeDebugPrivilege"` when run as admin.

Comment: use `EnumProcesses` very bad solution. need use `NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, ...)`, *checking if each exe has a different PID* - this not need check at all

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT does the code works on your machine ? RbMm if my code prints the process name correctly would already help

Comment: Seems that the processes which failed to open are [protected process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-), you could only open it with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | SYNCHRONIZE`. The following sample to list process with name works for me: [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `OpenProcess` failed and the `GetModuleBaseName` function was skipped. The processes you opened are [protected process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-). Even if you have the `SeDebugPrivilege` privilege, it can only allow `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|SYNCHRONIZE` access.

The following sample to list process with name works for me: [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes). And I made some simple modifications to meet your needs:

```
int main(void)
{
    int count = GetProcessCount(TEXT("notepad.exe"));
    _tprintf(TEXT("The Number of process %s has %d instance \n"), TEXT("notepad.exe"), count);
    return 0;
}

BOOL GetProcessCount(const TCHAR* name)
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD dwPriorityClass;
    int count = 0;
    // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printError(TEXT("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes)"));
        return(FALSE);
    }

    // Set the size of the structure before using it.
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    // Retrieve information about the first process,
    // and exit if unsuccessful
    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        printError(TEXT("Process32First")); // show cause of failure
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);          // clean the snapshot object
        return(FALSE);
    }

    // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and
    // display information about each process in turn
    do
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\n\n====================================================="));
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nPROCESS NAME:  %s"), pe32.szExeFile);
        _tprintf(TEXT("\n-------------------------------------------------------"));

        _tprintf(TEXT("\n  Process ID        = 0x%08X"), pe32.th32ProcessID);
        if (_tcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, name) == 0)
            count++;

    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    return count;
}


void printError(const TCHAR* msg)
{
    DWORD eNum;
    TCHAR sysMsg[256];
    TCHAR* p;

    eNum = GetLastError();
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, eNum,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
        sysMsg, 256, NULL);

    // Trim the end of the line and terminate it with a null
    p = sysMsg;
    while ((*p > 31) || (*p == 9))
        ++p;
    do { *p-- = 0; } while ((p >= sysMsg) &&
        ((*p == '.') || (*p < 33)));

    // Display the message
    _tprintf(TEXT("\n  WARNING: %s failed with error %d (%s)"), msg, eNum, sysMsg);
}
```

Comment: thank you I have tested it and its working, may I ask, in what case it could not count a process?